# how can i remove and replace jlabel with image icon in java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Im trying to create a banking system and to not make it boring we tried to add some image icon into the program in jlabel, when i tried to run the code and first pin mistake, removes the tester label successfully but the problem is when tries are equal to 4, Label pinwrongtester doesn't seem to remove instead it is mixing with the Label that i programmed when they entered pin 4 times, i hope you guys can help me to solve this mistakes

```
   public void Option()
{
    //option title
   JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose Options");
   label.setFont(new Font("Consolas",Font.BOLD,20));

   JButton choose = new JButton();
   choose.add(label);
   choose.setBounds(200,300,200,40);
   choose.setBackground(Color.white);
   choose.setEnabled(false);


   // Buttons Option 
   JButton Balance = new JButton("Balance");
   JButton Withdraw= new JButton("Withdraw");
   JButton Send = new JButton("Transfer");
   JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");


    //Set Bounds
    Balance.setBounds(50,350,200,40);
    Withdraw.setBounds(50,450,200,40);
    Send.setBounds(350,350,200,40);
    Exit.setBounds(350,450,200,40);

    //addActionListener
    Balance.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           pinbalance();
       }
   });
    Withdraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           pinwithdraw();
       }
   });
    Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           pintransferfunds();
       }
   });

   //add buttons and labels
   p.add(choose);
   p.add(Balance);
   p.add(Withdraw);
   p.add(Send);
   p.add(Exit);
}
JPanel enterpinbg;
JFrame enterpinframe;
String account_name;
String balance;
String pindb;

JLabel tester;
JLabel pinwrongtester;
JLabel pinwrongertester;
JLabel balancetester;

JFrame balanceframe;
JPanel balancepanel;

ImageIcon enteryourpin;
ImageIcon pinwrong;
ImageIcon pinwronger;
ImageIcon balanceicon;

private LinkedList<String> picturetrans;


JTextField inputpin;
boolean police = false;
int x =0;

public void pinbalance()
{

 //PIN FRAME
    enterpinframe = new JFrame("Enter Pin");
    enterpinframe.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    enterpinframe.setVisible(true);
    enterpinframe.setResizable(false);
    enterpinframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    enterpinframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



     //PIN PANEL  
    enterpinbg = new JPanel();
    enterpinbg.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    enterpinbg.setBackground(Color.orange);
    enterpinbg.setVisible(true);
    enterpinbg.setLayout(null);
    enterpinframe.add(enterpinbg);

  inputpin = new JTextField();
     inputpin.setFont(new Font("Consolas",Font.BOLD,20));
   inputpin.setForeground(Color.gray);

       //Setbounds
    inputpin.setBounds(250,600,100,40);


      //tester + image
     enteryourpin = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Enter yout      PIN.png"));
     tester = new JLabel(enteryourpin);
      tester.setBounds(50,50,500,500);




    //enterpin Add
     enterpinbg.add(tester);
    enterpinbg.add(inputpin);
     this.dispose();


    inputpin.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.getKeyCode()==(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER))

            {
            String pinx = inputpin.getText();
            Connection con= null;
            Statement stmt = null;
                try
                {
                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER1);
                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER2);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
                    stmt=con.createStatement();
                    String sql ="SELECT*FROM TBL_BANK WHERE PIN ='"+pinx+"' ";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                        pindb = rs.getString("PIN");
                        account_name = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NAME");
                        balance = rs.getString("BALANCE");    
                        }
                        rs.close();

                }
                catch(Exception f)
                {
                    System.out.println(f);
                }

                //if Login Success and Failed

                if(pinx.equals(pindb))
                { 
                  // Balance will show up

                 }

                else if(pinx!=(pindb))
                {

                    enterpinbg.remove(tester); 
                    x++;
                    System.out.println("x");
                    inputpin.setText("");


                    pinwrong = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PIN Wrong (1_2Times).png"));
                    pinwrongtester = new JLabel(pinwrong);
                    pinwrongtester.setBounds(50,50,500,500);
                    enterpinbg.add(pinwrongtester);

                     enterpinbg.repaint();

                    if(x>=4 )
                      {
                        // this doesnt quite work please help me fix it
                       enterpinbg.remove(pinwrongtester);
                       enterpinbg.repaint();


                       }


                }



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of reusing the JLabel and adding new ImageIcons, have you tried using different JLabels with a set ImageIcon?

Comment: i actually used different JLables in each ImageIcons

Comment: Have you tried using a layout manager? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html Normally that is how you'd place components on a panel.